# defining private MIB under experimental node

Tags: snmp, mib, oid

Any samples on how to define a private MIB containing some x objects? how do I register these MIBs and handle get requests to it?

Comment: Different SNMP agent frameworks use different approaches, so you will have to check out the documentation of the one you use.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by reading something like Net-SNMP's tutorial about [agent coding tutorials](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials#Coding_Tutorials).  But in the long run, if you need to write about MIBs you should probably also read either the SMIv2 RFCs (RFC2578 to get started) or a good book on SNMP and MIBs ("Understanding SNMP MIBs" is the classically referred to book).